# VL_SIFT - Undefined function or variable

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, sift, vlfeat

I try to make use of VLFeat library. So, I've downloaded the package and run vl_setup script. But when I create a new script and type this code:

```
I = imread('imhog.jpg');
image(I) ;

I = single(rgb2gray(I)) ;

[f,d] = vl_sift(I) ;

perm = randperm(size(f,2)) ;
sel = perm(1:50) ;
h1 = vl_plotframe(f(:,sel)) ;
h2 = vl_plotframe(f(:,sel)) ;
set(h1,'color','k','linewidth',3) ;
set(h2,'color','y','linewidth',2) ;

h3 = vl_plotsiftdescriptor(d(:,sel),f(:,sel)) ;
set(h3,'color','g') ;
```

it gives such error:

**vl_sift('imhog.jpg')**

**Undefined function or variable 'vl_sift'.**

Comment: Did you compile the VLFeat library from source or did you download the pre-compiled binaries?  Also, when you ran `vl_setup`, what exactly is the output?  The error can mean many things.  Please give us more.

Comment: Either the VLFeat library is not added to MATLAB `path` or the files have not been mex-ed properly i.e. the `vl_setup` script didn't finish successfully.

Comment: When I press button run in vl_setup script, it works,at least it does not give any error message in this case. When I choose as a folder ..../vl_feat/toolbox and type in command shell 

run('..../vlfeat-master/toolbox/vl_setup')

it does not give any message too. 
But here in this link - http://www.vlfeat.org/install-matlab.html, it writes that it has to be an output such as VLFeat 0.9.17 ready.

Comment: Then I've created a new script and typed above code, but whatever I choose as a path in a search folder, I cann't run vl_sift. @rayryeng

Comment: By the way, I  use Matlab trial version...@ParagS.Chandakkar

Comment: @sapio_l - Did you ensure that your MEX compiler is set up?  Did you do `mex -setup`?

Comment: The problem is I did not get how to do it even in this link:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html?refresh=true

I typed mex -setup and got: 

MEX configured to use 'Visual C++ 2015 Professional (C)' for C language compilation.
Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB variables with more than 2^32-1 elements.You will be required to update your code to utilize the new API.
 
To choose a different language, select one from the following:
 mex -setup C++ 
 mex -setup FORTRAN    
@rayryeng